# Possible to import Office365 users into local active directory domain?

Tags: active-directory, azure, single-sign-on, microsoft-office-365

My company has an office365 setup for all employees. We also have just implemented a domain controller locally which we want to use to authenticate a few things here in the office. The problem is that we want to have a way to use single sign on/password synchronization. The Azure dirsync tool syncs from the local domain controller up to office365, but not the other way around. Is it possible to get this done?